# Why is a Fourier series the same on $[-3,3]$ and on $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Tags: fourier-series

I have calculated the Fourier series in Mathematica for a function on an interval $[-3,3]$ and on an interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ and they are exactly the same.

The function is:

\begin{equation}
    f(\xi)=\begin{cases}
        2, \ \ \ \ -2\le \xi<-1 \\
        1, \ \ \ \ -1\le \xi<0 \\
        2, \ \ \ \ 0\le \xi<1 \\
        3, \ \ \ \ 1\le \xi\le2,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

They  seem scaled, but have not changed at all.

The core of this lies in the Fourier coefficients. Can someone explain how the Fourier coefficients become the same  on $[-3,3]$ and on an interval $[-\pi,\pi]$?

The coefficients are:

$$\alpha_0=\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^a f(\xi)d\xi$$

$$\alpha_k=\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^a f(\xi)\cos\omega k\xi d\xi$$

$$\beta_k=\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^a f(\xi)\sin\omega k\xi d\xi$$

Where $\omega=\frac{n\pi}{a}$

Comment: What was your function? What is $n$?

Comment: Do you mean you use $\omega = \frac{n\pi}{\pi}$ in one case and $\omega = \frac{n\pi}{3}$ in the other case?

Comment: @Gary n =20, update f.  GEdgar: Yes

Comment: Is $f$ zero outside of $[-2,2]$?

Comment: Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @JohnDouma Hahaha! It exists but not in that definition, it just appears as a new repeition of that function outside the interval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is obvious since once a periodic function can be represented as a linear combination of monotone harmonics, its *scaled* version can be represented as a linear combination of *scaled* monotone harmonics, with the same scale factor and linear combination coefficients. In mathematical language, if
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cos \frac{2n\pi}{T}x+b_n\sin \frac{2n\pi}{T}x
$$
and
$$
f(kx)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\cos \frac{2n\pi}{T/k}x+d_n\sin \frac{2n\pi}{T/k}x,
$$
then
$$
{
c_0=\frac{1}{T/k}\int_0^{T/k} f(kx)dx=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^{T} f(x)dx=a_0,
\\
c_{n\ge 1}=\frac{2}{T/k}\int_0^{T/k} f(kx)\cos \frac{2n\pi}{T/k}x dx=\frac{2}{T}\int_0^{T} f(x)\cos \frac{2n\pi}{T}x dx=a_n.
}
$$
similarly, $d_n=b_n.$

Comment: The first and second equations needs $a_0$ added in front of the sum

Comment: No need for them. The summation starts from $n=0$.

Comment: Right, didn't see that.